# How to set rails environment variables in database.yml file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, environment-variables, yaml

On my local machine, I want to set environment variables for all of the sensitive information in the database.yml file. My file looks like this:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: <%= ENV['DATABASE_USERNAME'] %> 
  password: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
  socket: <%= ENV['SOCKET'] %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV['DEVELOPMENT_DATABASE'] %>

test:
  <<: *default
  database: #JetStreamIQ-2_0_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV['PRODUCTION_DATABASE'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['DATABASE_USERNAME'] %> 
  password: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

I thought that I could just set these environment variables in my .bashrc file, but that doesn't seem to be working. My .bashrc file looks like this:

```
export DATABASE_USERNAME="root"
export DATABASE_PASSWORD="*****"
export SOCKET="/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock"
export DEVELOPMENT_DATABASE="shoppe_development"
export PRODUCTION_DATABASE="#"
```

When I run my server with

```
rails s
```

I get an error that says:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I understand that there is a problem with the database username and password because of the way I've configured my database.yml file, but I'm just not sure what it is.

Is there something big I'm missing here? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 37):

I'd like to offer a couple of tips here.

1. You can run database.yml through erb to test what you're getting.  For example, `erb config/database.yml`.  This will help you determine what the problem may be.
2. You can find out every environment variable set in your shell with the `set` command.  This will allow you to confirm that the environment variables you're expecting are being set (in `.bashrc`).

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: That's a cool trick with the 'erb config/database.yml' command. I didn't know you could do that. When I ran that command, it shows that all the fields where I have defined environment variables are empty.

Answer (score 5):

It turns out that after I edited my bashrc file, I needed to exit out of that terminal session and open another terminal for the changes to be finalized :/ After I did that my application started perfectly.

Comment: You're right - `.bashrc` is only loaded when you log in, so starting a new terminal session is one way to see your changes. Alternatively you could do `. .bashrc` to load the file without restating your session.

Comment: or a simple `source ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 3):

If you dont want to restart your terminal, you just need to execute your .bashrc file:

```
source /path/to/.bashrc
```

in the same terminal as your rails server.

Answer (score 2):

Is it a typo or are you really setting `JETSTREAMIQ_DATABASE_PASSWORD` but then using `DATABASE_PASSWORD` in your `database.yml`? Because that would do it.

Can you connect to mysql using the actual values directly using the `mysql` command line app?

Comment: No that was a typo; sorry about that, I just edited my post. Yes I can connect with the values in my bashrc file if I simply enter them when using the mysql command line.

Answer (score 2):

you may need to put your environment variables at the top of `.bashrc` file. cause it has some return executed into the file. so it return before actually executing your `export` command

something like this:

nano ~/.bashrc

```
export DATABASE_VAR="my_own_var"

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply set environment variable

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://user:pass@localhost/dbname
```

It will override `database.yml` settings

Offcourse it supports more parameters, like

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql2://user:passwd@host:port/dbname?encoding=utf8mb4&collation=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also source your ~/.bashrc file using the following command on your terminal:

`exec $SHELL`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to access your local database with that data from the console?
Maybe you have to grant access for localhost

`GRANT ALL ON shoppe_development.* TO 'root'@'localhost';`

Besides that, I recommend you the gem [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) to handle your env vars for development environment